# Is MapGuide still maintained?

Tags: c#, .net, mapguide

I want to use a free or at least a cheap alternative to ArcGIS Server that I can develop for in .NET.
MapGuide used to be such.

Is it still maintained?

Comment: I think it got split into commercial (AutoDesk) and community https://mapguide.osgeo.org/.  I think there is also MapWindow as a .NET project

Comment: is it an installation? can I used it in shared hosting environment?

Comment: You can check the recent activity directly from the trac https://trac.osgeo.org/mapguide/timeline?from=Jan+26%2C+2016&daysback=60&authors=&milestone=on&ticket=on&changeset=on&wiki=on&update=Update

Comment: @user5495269 MapGuide comes in Windows installers and binary tarballs (for CentOS 6.x) and deb packages (Ubuntu 12)

Shared hosting is a tough one because MapGuide demands specific requirements that a shared hosting environment may not satisfy (eg. A specific version of Apache, PHP, Java, .net)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, MapGuide is still maintained.

We do new major releases on a yearly basis, with minor point releases as the need arises.

Source: Me, I do the releases for MapGuide Open Source